# Flutter - Making a column / widget variable width with others fixed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a flutter application with 2 pieces (and more later) that need to have a "variable width" element surrounded by fixed-width items;
eg as a DataTable (I want Name to grow/shrink when the screen is rotated, but the others are fixed):

```
  SingleChildScrollView dataBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        sortAscending: sort,
        sortColumnIndex: 0,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
              label: Text("Name"),
              numeric: false,
              tooltip: "Device Name",
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                setState(() {
                  sort = !sort;
                });
                onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
              }),
          DataColumn(
              label: Text("RSSI"),
              numeric: true,
              tooltip: "Signal Strength",
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                setState(() {
                  sort = !sort;
                });
                onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
              }),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Node"),
            numeric: true,
            tooltip: "Mesh Node",
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Status"),
            numeric: false,
            tooltip: "Status",
          ),
        ],
```

And as 2 items in a Row() container (where I'd like the graph to be variable-width and the slider to stay fixed -- and ideally I'd like the graph to be pinch-resizable and then scrollable with the height of the slider always corresponding to the graph):

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[Text('HeaderJunk')]),
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Slider(
                        value: setpoint * 1.0,
                        max: 900,
                        min: 200,
                        onChanged: (double value) {
                          setState(() {
                            setpoint = value.toInt();
                          });
                        })),
                chartwidget //This is a chart_flutter chart
              ]),
```

Comment: Please be more clear with your question and ask one thing and not multiple questions. it is very difficult to understand what you are requesting

Answer (score 1):

Ahah!
The short answer is to use the Expand container... on a Widget (you can't use it on a Datacolumn).  Tested with emulator; resulting code is:

```
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        sortAscending: sort,
        sortColumnIndex: 0,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(child: Text("NAME")),//<=== Expand the Label
              numeric: false,
              tooltip: "Device Name",
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                setState(() {
                  sort = !sort;
                });
                onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
              }),
          DataColumn(
              label: Text("RSSI"),
              numeric: true,
              tooltip: "Signal Strength",
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                setState(() {
                  sort = !sort;
                });
                onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
              }),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Node"),
            numeric: true,
            tooltip: "Mesh Node",
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Status"),
            numeric: false,
            tooltip: "Status",
          ),
        ],
```

and

```
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[Text('Foto-captor description and such')]),
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Slider(
                        value: setpoint * 1.0,
                        max: 900,
                        min: 200,
                        onChanged: (double value) {
                          setState(() {
                            setpoint = value.toInt();
                          });
                        })),
                Expanded(child: chartwidget)
              ]),
```